# JmsI18RoutingBundle permanent redirect false

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

I'm using the bundled jmsI18RoutingBundle, but encounter a problem with the redirect when I use the `prefix` strategy.

In fact, in the vps panel puts me attention that the http status code is 302.

Reading in the code bundle, however, should set the redirect permanent 301!

There is a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Does that make sense for conditional redirects?
One user might be redirected to page A, another might be redirected to page B.